# how to export dump file from postgreSQL usnig php

Tags: php, postgresql

i have a project using postgreSQL as a database and i need query or script to make compressed  dump file like this 'backup-1-1-2020.dump' compressed from this database using php ?

any help or idea to make it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exec()` or `system()` in php to call `pg_dump`. The exact options you need to pass for `pg_dump` cannot be told from your question.

One hint, though: Format date in your filename as yyyy-mm-dd if possible. This way directory listing sorted by filename will sort backups in chronological order.